# What are the key classic philosophical/religious texts in Latin?

Tags: text-corpus, ancient-greek

These are the top texts in different languages I have gathered:

- Torah (Hebrew)
- Tao Te Ching (Chinese)
- Rig Veda (Sanskrit)
- Perfection of Wisdom (Tibetan)
- Quran (Arabic)
- New Testament (Greek)
- Tirukkural (Tamil)
- Metamorphoses? (Latin)

The Torah is probably the most important Hebrew book, the Quran for Arabic books, the Perfection of Wisdom is a very well known Tibetan one, the New Testament in Greek (though it also came shortly after in Latin, I am ignoring it for this question since it was already done in Greek).

Metamorphoses doesn't seem on par with these other texts. Is there anything in Latin on-par with these texts (that is also available online somewhere in text format)?

If you measure purely by [most translated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_literary_works_by_number_of_translations), the bible and tao te ching are at the top.

I would say Plotinus' Enneads but that is Greek lol.

Perhaps it is something in [Christian Latin Literature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_Latin_literature). Or maybe [Patrologia Latina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patrologia_Latina), that looks way too big though compared to these books. Maybe [Liturgical_books_of_the_Roman_Rite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liturgical_books_of_the_Roman_Rite).

Comment: _Summa Theologiae_ surely must be the elephant in the room.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel does it exist online anywhere in full in Latin? http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/aquinas/summa.shtml is missing most of it. Ah looks like it might be [here](https://www.logicmuseum.com/wiki/Authors/Thomas_Aquinas/Summa_Theologiae/Part_IIa).

Comment: @LancePollard—Absolutely. Aquinas, Thomas. *Summa Theologica.* Paris: Bloud, 1880. 8 volumes. Type **summatheologica0#thomuoft** in the archive.org search field, but replace the # symbol with a number from 1-8.

Comment: There is also Augustine’s *De civitate Dei contra paganos* (“On the City of God against the Pagans”).

Comment: @DerÜbermensch You could post those two as an answer or even two. They are certainly good candidates.

Comment: This is a very broad/vague question. What makes something a top text?

Comment: @TKR I agree--this really needs to be made more specific, e.g. "Did the Romans have a 'holy book' like the Bible?" As it stands, almost any famous book written in Latin could be an answer.

Comment: As the question stands now, it seems to be more along the line of ‘Which is the key book of the Roman culture?’ The real problem with the question, as I see it, is not the effort, it’s not the contents, but the question itself. I believe the question is interesting in and of itself, and if ‘Roman culture’ is delimited by time, such as ‘of the Roman culture, understood as _ab urbe condītā_ to 330 C.E.’ I believe that would include all Roman culture as most understand it and clearly demarcate the Byzantine culture as a new chapter (if not a book) of its cultural history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps [Vergil's *Aeneid*](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/vergil/aen1.shtml) could easily fit in this scope.

Comment: I would easily upvote this, if you could also provide a brief summary of why you believe so. (Most, if not all ancient authors, mediaeval authors and modern authors probably agree with you, though, as do I (though my opinion on this matters but a little).